# Django celery in docker looking for already deleted tasks

Tags: django, docker, rabbitmq, celery, docker-compose

I have set up my celery app for django and have been using docker for running it.
I once run the code with following CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE

```
# define scheduled tasks here
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test-scheduler': {
        'task': 'users.tasks.test_print',
        'schedule': 10,  # in seconds, or timedelta(seconds=10)
    },
}
```

And, it works fine.

Later on, I changed the name of my tasks as follows:

```
# define scheduled tasks here
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'handle-email': {
        'task': 'users.tasks.handle_email_task',
        'schedule': 10,  # in seconds, or timedelta(seconds=10)
    },
}
```

But, When I run `docker-compose up --build`, following error is showing up.

```
worker_1  | 2017-06-16T15:17:22.844376379Z KeyError: 'users.tasks.test_print'
worker_1  | 2017-06-16T15:17:52.849843783Z [2017-06-16 15:17:52,848: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'users.tasks.test_print'.
```

Did I miss anything? Need help to solve it.